# C# regular expression question

Tags: c#, html, regex

Can anybody help me to form a regular expression to search the following string:

```
<b>The</b> <b>brown</b> <b>fox</b> jumped over the <b>lazy</b> <b>dog</b>.
```

The expression should match `<b>The</b> <b>brown</b> <b>fox</b>` as one match then proceed to match `<b>lazy</b> <b>dog</b>`. In this example, the expression should return two matches only, thanks.

Comment: `var regex = new Regex("(The brown fox|lazy dog)");`. Either this does what you want perfectly, or you should provide more information.

Comment: @FadeIMS, what is it that you really want to learn? Isn't it better to understand Regex and be able to write your own regexps than asking on each individual case?

Comment: You probably want to search words in HTML bold tags. <b>The brown fox</b> jumped over the <b>lazy dog</b>?

Comment: Yes, Arseny, but the tags didn't show up. How can I do that.

Comment: Edited your question, use the html encoded version of < (&lt;) and > (&gt;)

Comment: So to get this straight: You want to parse HTML with Regex? Answer: Don't. Use a proper HTML parser such as exists in HTMLAgilityPack

Comment: @FadelMS: I've edited the question to demonstrate two better ways of displaying HTML markup; is that what you intended?  Check out the Markdown editing help (the orange question-mark icon above the textarea); there's a lot of good stuff there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"<b>[^<]*</b>(?:\s*<b>[^<]*</b>)*");

String input = @"<b>The</b> <b>brown</b> <b>fox</b> jumped over the <b>lazy</b> <b>dog</b>.";
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(input))
{
  Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

output:

> `<b>The</b> <b>brown</b> <b>fox</b>`
>   `<b>lazy</b> <b>dog</b>`

Answer (score 1):

This would work with your specific example:

```
@"The brown fox|lazy dog"
```

Furthermore, if you need to match any more simple phrases, just append `|the simple phrase` to this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
The brown fox|lazy dog
```

The above is the regex that would generate two matches from your given input.

Comment: Sorry gentlemen, I don't know how to include tags in the question. My original question included bold tags. Could anybody show me how to include html tags?

Answer (score 0):

[RegEx really isn't suited to parsing HTML](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). A much better solution would be to use the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)

Comment: Here is my input corrected: The &lt;b&gt;brown&lt;/b&gt; &lt;b&gt;fox&lt;/b&gt; jumped over the &lt;b&gt;lazy&lt;/b&gt; &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt;